# Return result from xml tree iterator

Tags: xml, python-3.x, recursion, lxml

I have an xml tree:

```
<root>
    <expression>
        <add>
            <number>1</number>
            <number>2</number>
            <number>3</number>
        </add>
    </expression>
</root>
```

My function iterates over the tree, adding the int of the child text. The final result of the print statement is the result I need, but how do I return it from the addleafnodes function?

```
root = etree.XML(request.data['expression'])
results = 0

def addleafnodes(root, results):
    for child in root:
        if root.tag != "root" and root.tag != "expression":
            results += int(child.text)
        print(results)
        addleafnodes(child, results)

newresults = addleafnodes(root, results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `results` down the recursion, and increment, but never return it back "up". If `results` was an object, and you were simply passing a reference, you could look at it after the root-call to `addleafnodes`.

The following will return the sum back up the recursion:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML

expr = """<root>
    <expression>
        <add>
            <number>1</number>
            <number>2</number>
            <number>3</number>
        </add>
    </expression>
</root>
"""
root = XML(expr)

def addleafnodes(root, results):
    for child in root:
        if root.tag != "root" and root.tag != "expression":
            results += int(child.text)
        results = addleafnodes(child, results)
    return results

newresults = addleafnodes(root, 0)
print(newresults)
```

I think this functional approach is good, but you could also simply update the global variable from inside the recursion (I've removed `results = 0` from this snippet).

Note, I'm not sure if the code breaks with deeper structures of expressions (e.g. nested adds etc.).

Comment: It may break with deeper structures, but I think I have it a bit clearer in my head - the problem I have to solve does involve deeper structures, but I want to solve as much of it myself as I can!

Comment: Good luck! Otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: I appreciate your help and most likely will ask - but I'm going to keep at it for now

Comment: Hey Jeppe I had a crack at it - still some issues - if you don;t mind taking a look it's at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446862/return-result-from-arbitrarily-nested-xml-tree-sum

Answer (score 0):

You have your question tagged `lxml`. If you're really using lxml you can use the [`sum()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-sum) xpath function to simplify...

```
from lxml import etree

expr = """<root>
    <expression>
        <add>
            <number>1</number>
            <number>2</number>
            <number>3</number>
        </add>
    </expression>
</root>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(expr)


def addleafnodes(elem):
    return int(elem.xpath("sum(.//add/number)"))


newresults = addleafnodes(root)
print(newresults)
```

Printed output...

```
6
```

Also [see here for more info on xpath in lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath).

Comment: I saw the sum method - I also want to use different maths operators